# Trigonometry tangent line question

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives

How would I figure this out.

Find all x values between $0$ and $2\pi$ where the line tangent to the graph of

$y=\frac{\cos x}{2+ \sin(x)}$ is horizontal.

I did the deriavative

$\frac{(2+\sin(x)-\sin(x)+\cos(x)\cos(x)}{(2+\sin x)^2}$ but I think I need to find $x$

Comment: You have a mistake in your derivative calculation. Give it another try and put the steps here so that we can tell you what went wrong. Once you have the correct derivative, it will be pretty easy to see when it's $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The denominator is nice and safe. The numerator is $(2+\sin x)(-\sin x)-\cos^2 x$. (There was a sign error here, and missing parentheses.)

But $\cos^2 x=1-\sin^2 x$, so the numerator simplifies **very** nicely to $-2\sin x-1$. There are a couple of places (third quadrant, fourth quadrant) where this is $0$.

Comment: yes I made a sign error I did not see to much math in one day...

Answer (score 2):

The derivative seems to be incorrect:

$$\left(\frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}\right)'=\frac{-\sin x(2+\sin x)-\cos^2x}{(2+\sin x)^2}=0\Longleftrightarrow -2\sin x-1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\sin x=-\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow x=\begin{cases}\frac{7\pi}{6}\\{}\\\frac{11\pi}{6}\end{cases}\;\;+2k\pi\;\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;\;\ldots$$

Comment: I see you multiply $cos(x)$ and $cos(x)$

Comment: Sí, claro...en el denominador, ¿no? (Yes, of course...in the denominator, right?)

Comment: In this case there's no need to add $2k\pi$ because the problem statement restricts $x$ to $[0,2\pi ]$.

Comment: yes indeed gracias senor.

Comment: That is (well, *was*) for the OP to notice, @AméricoTavares

Comment: @DonAntonio I see now.

Answer (score 1):

For a horizontal tangent line you need the derivative to be zero. After all, $\operatorname{d}\!y/\!\operatorname{d}\!x$ gives you the gradient of the tangent line to the graph $y=f(x)$. We are told that

$$y = \frac{\cos x}{2+\sin x}$$

Using the quotient rules, and the standard trig identity $\sin^2x+\cos^2x \equiv 1$ we see that

$$\frac{\operatorname{d}\!y}{\operatorname{d}\!x} = \frac{1+2\sin x}{\cos^2x-4\sin x-5} \equiv \frac{1+2\sin x}{(2+\sin x)^2}$$

Since $-1 \le \sin x \le 1$ for all real $x$ it follows that the horizontal tangent lines are gives by $1+2\sin x = 0$. In other words $\sin x = -\frac{1}{2}$. The principal value of which is $x=-\frac{\pi}{6}$. Plotting the graph of $y=\sin x$ and the line $y=-\frac{1}{2}$ can help to find the other solutions. We have:

$$x \in \left\{2\pi n - \frac{\pi}{6} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\} \cup \left\{(2n+1)\pi + \frac{\pi}{6} : n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$$

Restricting this to the interval $[0,2\pi]$ we have $x=\frac{7}{6}\pi$ and $x=\frac{11}{6}\pi$.